# Rmarkdown Runs, but Produces Connection Error on Publishing

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I have an Rmarkdown file which currently does not need to `source()` to other scripting files. There are currently two parameters in the YAML: a `numeric` input and a `file` upload for .CSVs

When I "knit with parameters" locally the file runs fine, I've even moved it out of my existing RProj to various other locations on my computer to make sure the working director doesn't matter and the place I'm grabbing .csv files from doesn't impact the knitting process.

When I attempt to publish to my RStudio Connect account I get the following two errors:

`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`

`Calls: local ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.table -> file`

This is my current YAML for reference:

```
---
title: "CPR Report Card"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
params: 
  data:
    label: "Input Zoll Dataset:"
    value: ".csv"
    input: file 
  age:
    label: "Age of Patient"
    value: 0
    input: numeric
    min: 0
    max: 17.75
    step: .25

---
```

So, locally and across computers the file works fine. Seems like it should publish ok to RStudio Connect but currently isn't. This is my first foray into Connect, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: RStudio Connect is a premium service. Perhaps you could address your concerns to the company?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Roman, I contacted the company and a few other resources.

It would seem that `read.csv()` from my markdown was the issue due to the need for a reactive value that something like Shiny can supply. Unfortunately it seems that rmarkdown alone won't solve this issue and I'll need to translate this over to a Shiny app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communicating with the RStudio Connect support service, using read.csv() from an Rmarkdown file causes issues since the markdown does not have a reactive component to interact with the user's file system. If you wish to have this functionality it's best to look into developing a Shiny application.